# Android : Saripaar Validation Library. Need to set error message from strings.xml

Tags: validation, user-interface, android-annotations, saripaar

I am using the the Saripaar validation library https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar to validate one of the forms.
The library is pretty useful as it avoids a lot of boilerplate code for validating a form.
However, the library uses annontations on widgets.
Below is an example:

```
@Password(order = 1)
@TextRule(order = 2, minLength = 6, message = "Enter at least 6 characters.")
private EditText passwordEditText;
```

The order attribute is the one that specifies the order in which the validations are going 
to take place. Here is my problem: the message attribute takes a constant expression.
I need to set this from string Resource file. So that error messages can be internationalized later. I have already tried below:

```
message = getResources().getString(R.string.err_msg)
```

But it doesnt seem to work as it needs compile time constants.

Can anyone help me with the same or guide me through a workaround?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this syntax :

```
//private variable in the class declaration section
private EditText txtFirstName=null; 
@Required(order = 2,  messageResId  = R.string.err_required_field)
```

It's in the lib's documentation (and the lib itself is an excellent one).

Comment: Thanx a lot mate. Found it in documentation after you pointed out. Thanks again

Comment: @Viren Could you point me the link to this lib's documentation. I couldn't found anything related with documentation on his library github repo .

Comment: The documentation in the Github repo is partial. there is not documentation on the messageResId option.